# create multiple vue-elements of the same component in js-script

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vue.js

my problem is the following:
I want to create some vue elements like this:

```js
var rRow = document.createElement('rightrow');
```

rightRow is a vue Element and should be importet like this:

```html
<rightRow></rightRow>
```

As I look into Chrome Developer Tools, the HTML code looks as it shoukd be, but the vue element isn't there. If I insert it 'by hand'(just write  where it should be) it works, but I need it more often. Thanks to every helping hand :D

Sorry if my english isn't the best. I'm no native speaker xD

EDIT:
In my Chrome-Developer-Tools the component  can be seen. I just need to know how I can render it again because the text is right but the Vue-View isn't

Comment: `document.createElement('rightrow');`  This isn't how to create Vue components. You have to let Vue draw the DOM elements.  Vue has an [excellent Getting Started guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) -- you really ought to read through it

Answer (score 1):

Vue uses the ES2015 class sytax and can instantiated via their constructors.

```
import RightRow from "./RightRow.vue"
const rrow = new RightRow();
```

Comment: And how do I implement this in my HTML source?

Comment: If you used `Vue.component('right-row', ...)` then you can use `<right-row>` in your HTML

Comment: but I need to implement with my js source, because there have to be more of them and the number is variable